# getting CRC error while decompressing a gzip file in python

Tags: python, gzip

I am trying to decompress a big gzip file (2GB). If I use the read() function, it freezes my computer due to so much of data. So, looking at another answer on stackoverflow, I used the approach of reading the gzip file line by line

```
inF = gzip.open(compressed_file_name, 'rb')
outF = open(outfilename, 'wb')
for line in inF:
    outF.write(line)
inF.close()
outF.close()
```

However, at the end of the file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in download_latest_file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 455, in readline
    c = self.read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 261, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 308, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 347, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0x3b5a517c != 0x643d9301L
```

My python version is 2.7.6

Comment: Can you decompress it using other means? i.e. Have you eliminated the possibility that the file is corrupt?

Comment: yes, gzip -d works fine

Comment: Try with a different zip file to make sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: Run qunzip -t -v on your file to test it verbosely. Is it OK?

Comment: Your code works.  Either the file is corrupted or Python 2.7.6 has a bug, possibly with respect to very large files.  What is the uncompressed size of the data in bytes, exactly?

Comment: Uncompressed file size is 1.9 GB. I had to change my code to use the call command instead. `call(["gzip", "-d", "-f", compressed_file_name])` Its working fine. Which explains that there is no issue with the file

Comment: its not consistent actually. sometimes succeeds sometimes fails. Works perfectly fine in node.js so there must be some issue with python